# To take input element value's length in angular 2/4 form

Tags: angular2-forms, angular4-forms

In my angualr 2 template form, I've input field designed in a way like on `focus`, label animates on top of the input element and on `focus-out` label comes down back to the input element.[similar like this one : [codepen]](https://codepen.io/leogono/pen/EPeVgz)

My problem is the label comes down even when control has values which should be handled in code. I don't know how to take the length of the input element to check in my `component` to keep the label on top.

HTML :

```
<form #queryForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="Search(queryForm.value)">
<div class="form-input">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="animate-label"
        (focusout)="onLeave(queryForm.value)" name="process" ngModel [ngClass]="{'ontop':hasValue}">
        <label>Process</label>
    </div>
```

Component :

```
export class FormTemplate{
hasValue:boolean;

onLeave(form:any){ //is this the right way to get the value back to component??
    console.log(form)
    if(form.process.length>0) //syntax??
    {
        this.hasValue=true;
    }
}}
```

When the element has value, i'll add up the `ngClass` `#hasValue` to keep label on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
<input type="text" class="animate-label"
    (focusout)="onLeave(queryForm.value)" name="process" [(ngModel)]="process" [ngClass]="{'ontop': process?.length}">
    <label>Process</label>
```

Then you can remove `onLeave` and `hasValue` altogether.

The problem is that you provided an empty `ngModel` which won't do anything.

I don't know how your model looks but you might want to bind `process` to an object like `[(ngModel)]="someObject.process"` instead.